# Calculation of posterior distribution of a Gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process

Suppose I have a set of points $Y$, $X$ and I model them by using a Gaussian process $\mathcal{GP}(m,K)$. Let the noisy observations be given by

$$y^i = f^i + \sigma^2$$

$p(f)$ gives the prior on the Gaussian process. Then what will be the posterior $p(f|Y,Z)$ which is again a Gaussian process with a mean $(m',K')$. How  can $(m',K')$ be derived?

Comment: Can you clarify your notations ? In particular, you didn't defined Z which appears in your posterior p(f|Y,Z).

Answer (score 5):

In such a case the covariance function is changed. Let's fix notation. Suppose that we have a sample $D = (X,\mathbf{y}) = \{(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i)\}_{i = 1}^N$. The observations $y_i$ have the form 
$$
y_i = y(\mathbf{x}_i) = f(\mathbf{x}_i) + \epsilon_i.
$$
There $f_i = f(\mathbf{x}_i)$ is a true function value at the point $\mathbf{x}_i$, noise $\epsilon_i$ has an iid normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. $f$ is a gaussian process with zero mean and covariance function 
$$
cov(f(\mathbf{x}_i), f(\mathbf{x}_j)) = k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j).
$$

Due to noise, the covariance function for $y$ is 
$$
cov(y_i, y_j) = cov(f_i + \epsilon_i, f_j + \epsilon_j) = cov(f_i, f_j) + cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) = k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) + \sigma^2 \delta(\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j).
$$ 
There $\delta(x_1 - x_2)$ is a delta function: $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ equals $1$ for $\mathbf{x} = 0$ and zero for other $\mathbf{x}$; $k(x_1, x_2)$ is an old covariance function.

The posterior mean has the form:
$$
m = \mathbf{k} K^{-1} \mathbf{y}.
$$
There $K = \{k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j)\}_{i, j = 1}^N$ is a covariance matrix. Due to change of the covariance function one has to use instead the new covariance matrix $K' = K + \sigma^2 I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix); the covariance vector $\mathbf{k}$ is unchanged, so the new equation is 
$$
m = \mathbf{k} (K')^{-1} \mathbf{y}.
$$
The formula for the posterior variance is derived in the same way.

Comment: Very nice, clear answer.

Comment: I am having a doubt. how can the true function value $f_i = f(\mathbf{x}_i)$ can be calculated?

Comment: If we set noise level to zero, then we get that $m(\mathbf{x}_i) = y_i$ as the product $\mathbf{k}$ and $K^{-1}$ in this case equals corresponding row of identity matrix.

Comment: @AlexeyZaytsev, your definition of [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is incorrect. You should probably switch to Kronecker notation $\delta_{ij}$ judging by the context of your answer. Dirac delta is usually defined via integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)dx=1$ and $\delta(0)=\infty$ and $\delta(x\ne 0)=0$

Comment: @Aksakal fixed, thx

Comment: How do we know that the posterior will be a gaussian process?

Comment: @Abhay we can prove using the definition of GP and considering a joint distribution for any set of points