# Dirac delta function for multivariate input (in the context of Gaussian processes)

Tags: gaussian-process, dirac-delta

Let's say we have a set of $N$ observations $D = \{\bf X, t\}$ where ${\bf X} = [{\bf x}_1, ..., {\bf x}_N]^T$ are the locations and ${\bf t} = [t_1, ..., t_N]^T$ are the targets.

When applying a Gaussian process for the problem of regression, we start with an assumption that

\begin{equation}
    t_i = f_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

where $t_i$ is the observed targets, $f_i$ is a random variable that is the output at location ${\bf x}_i$, and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is assumed noise. We are then interested in the joint marginal distribution of ${\bf t}$, which we find to be

\begin{equation}
    {\bf t} \sim \mathcal{N}({\bf t}|{\bf 0}, {\bf C})
\end{equation}

where the covariance matrix $\bf C$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
    {\bf C}_{n,m} = k({\bf x}_n, {\bf x}_m) + \sigma^2\delta_{n,m}
\end{equation}

---

The book I'm reading this from (*Pattern recognition and Machine Learning*, Bishop 2006, pp 306) does not explain what $\delta_{n,m}$ is, but from [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/47141/247889) I've come to understand that this is the Dirac delta function

\begin{equation}
    \delta_{n,m} = \delta({\bf x}_n - {\bf x}_m)
\end{equation}

Any definition I've found assumes the input is univariate (one-dimensional), but the book strongly suggests that the input is multivariate.

**My question is this**: what is the definition of the Dirac delta function for multivariate input?

Comment: I believe this $\delta_{n,m}$ must be the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), not the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirac's delta notation is $\delta(x)$. When you see indices used $\delta_{ij}$, it must be [Kroneker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). In Bishop's book you can see how these two notation are used. For instance, check Exercise 3.4 for the latter, and Eq.4.146 for the former.

Comment: Just to be clear, the person (Alexey Zaytsev) who referred to this function as the 'Dirac delta function' in the question I linked to was wrong?

Comment: @Mossmyr, I wanted to say "No", but the way he defines Dirac delta $\delta(x)$ is wrong. I'm going to comment on his answer now.

Comment: @Akasal But Alexey is talking about the same thing as Bishop (pp 306-307): the covariance of the marginal distribution of the target in a Gaussian process. They use different variable names (Alexey uses $y_i = f_i + \epsilon_i$ while Bishop uses $t_i = y_i + \epsilon_i$), but it's the same thing. Edit: I see that you changed your comment now, disregard my comment.

Comment: @Mossmyr, yes, I think he meant to use Kronecker delta. Dirac delta is not an ordinary function, it's a *generalized* function and is defined through integrals