# Posterior distribution for a Gaussian Process with a transformation in a gaussian likelihood

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, references, gaussian-process, derivative

Suppose we are modelling observations y as follows. Our likelihood is normal $ y \sim \mathcal{N}(g(f(x)), \mathcal{I}\sigma^2)$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity matrix and $g$ is some function which takes the parameters $f(x)$ as input (another model). We put a GP prior on f: $f \sim \mathcal{G}\mathcal{P}(\mu, \Sigma)$.

In general, what can be said about the posterior $\pi(f \vert x, y, \sigma^2, \mu, \Sigma)$? In the special case of g being the identity function, we are in the usual scenario of a GP posterior. But is this also the case if g is an arbitrary well behaved function?

**My intuition so far**
This again will be a GP posterior. Proceeding like in the usual case of identity (see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47117/calculation-of-posterior-distribution-of-a-gaussian-process)), denoting noise $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathcal{I}\sigma^2)$, we can write:
\begin{align}
cov(y_i, y_j) = cov(g(f(x_i)) + \epsilon_i, g(f(x_j)) + \epsilon_j) = cov(g(f(x_i)), g(f(x_j))) + cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j)
\end{align}

So, given that we know the matrix $cov(f(x_i), f(x_j)) = \Sigma$, the challenge becomes to compute the matrix $cov(g(f(x_i)), g(f(x_j)))$.

According to [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82524737.pdf), for two RVs $X, Y$, we have
\begin{align}
cov(X, Y) = \iint H(x, y) - F(x)G(y)dxdy,
\end{align}
as well as
\begin{align}
cov(g(X), g(Y)) = \iint \left(H(x, y) - F(x)G(y)\right)g^{'}(x)g^{'}(y)dxdy,
\end{align}
where $H$ is their joint CDF and $F, G$ are marginal CDFs. Here, both $X, Y$ will be normal random variables, which suggests something similar to [Stein's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma) by using integration by parts, but I can't see the end.

Working through it, and effectively using Stein's lemma twice, I obtain:
\begin{align}
cov(g(X), g(Y)) = cov(X, g(Y))\mathbb{E}(g^{'}(X)) = cov(X, Y)\mathbb{E}(g^{'}(X))\mathbb{E}(g^{'}(Y))
\end{align}

Hence, what we need to do is to compute the expectation of gradients of $g$ with respect to the normal distribution law - here I'm not sure how to proceed in practice.

Comment: I do not entirely understand what you are doing. If $f(x)$ is a GP, why should $g(f(x))$ be a GP as well? I am also slightly confused by $\mathcal{N}(g(f(x)), \sigma^2\mathcal{I})$. Doesn't this notation mean the covariance is $\sigma^2\mathcal{I}$? And the first argument should be a mean function(!) not a process?

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the bits you seem to be confused about, let me know if something is still unclear. It doesn't have to be that g(f(x)) is a GP, but it's possible, e.g. applying a linear operator to a GP results in a GP.

I have overlooked the comment on the mean function. Still not sure what implications it has for the analysis above though.